# How do you reference a variable within a string in UNIX?

Tags: unix, scripting, ksh

I am writing a new script that creates aliases based on the results of an ls query. The script itself is simple enough, however what is hanging me up is the alias call. I cannot figure out how to reference the variable that I've generated in another string when I call the alias command:

```
for f in `ls -1 -O dir /dev/fs/`
do
  fl=`echo $f | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
  alias "$fl"_drive='cd /dev/fs/$f'
done
```

It's that reference to the $f variable in the alias call that's throwing me off. Can anyone shed some light on the proper syntax for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you properly want `$f` to point to the file you currently loop over.

The shell doesn't expand anything inside single quotes (`'`), so your alias contains a literal `$f`. Use double quotes instead.

```
alias "$fl"_drive="cd /dev/fs/$f"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
alias "${fl}_drive"="cd /dev/fs/$f"
```